# How to access function in bashrc at new terminal

Tags: bash, function, shell, unix, command

I created a function in `.bashrc` like this;

```
 #!/bin/bash
 function test() { ls; }
 export -f test
```

and call it in new terminal like this;

```
$ test
```

the result is `test: command not found`

What did I do wrong to access a function in `.bashrc` ?

Comment: Did you run `source .bashrc` before calling the function?

Comment: funny, because the `test` exists on any system.

Comment: Where did you write your `.bashrc` file? And, are you in fact running `bash`?

Comment: @jm666 test is not the real name of the function. I made it up here and i hate foo and bar

Comment: @codeforester Yeah I tried that, nothing changed

Comment: Are you actually calling `ls` in the `test` function, or is that a placeholder as well?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Do I need to create another `.bashrc` file. Can't I write a function and export it to an already existing `.bashrc` file?

Comment: @JonnyHenly `ls` is one of the commands in that function

Answer (score 2):

The function is not defined until `.bashrc` is sourced, either explicitly or on start-up by a *non-login* interactive shell. If your terminal starts a login shell, then the file will not be sourced.

You do not need to export the function.

Comment: What are you saying is that I need to run `source .bashrc` as far as I understand. I did that but same result came up.

Comment: You need to put some actual facts in your question: the *exact* file you are sourcing, along with the command you are running that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to make a ".function" file in your home directory and source it in your .bashrc.

**Before:** As seen below, it doesn't work.

```
%_Host@User> add 2 3
bash: add: command not found...
```

**Define a function in $HOME/.function**

```
%_Host@User> cat ~/.function
add ()
{
        echo "$1 + $2" | bc
}
```

**Here is how I am sourcing all functions in my $HOME/.bashrc**

```
%_Host@User> cat ~/.bashrc|grep source|grep func
        source $HOME/.function
%_Host@User>
```

*You may need to bash it or re-login again or just type bash on prompt and it should work.*

**Now it works:**

```
%_Host@User> add 2 3
5
%_Host@User>
```

Please give it a try. Thanks.